# Admob plugin for unity crashing my game on Android 5.0

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, admob

just launched my game on Google Play Store, at first I got Google Play Services running for leaderboards and achievements, but after I added admob I got some crash reports from Android 5.0 while in my phone 4.4 works just fine, I tested on a friend's phone with Android 5.0 and he play for a few secs and the game crashes, here is one of the crash reports that i received. It doesn't feel very useful but I don't know what to bring you to analyze, ask me anything you need if you think you can help. 
Google Play Services and Admob used in the game are both official plugins from Google.

[Crash Report](http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/attachments/45210-ss2015-04-25at112949.png)

Comment: Are you sure your admob is causing the problem? Try removing the admob and then test it with your friend's phone. If you are then sure, check you have your sdk and plugin updated. If they are up to date, check for any unity3d bug on their forum for your version. Some workaround may solve your issue. Hope it helps.

Comment: Pretty sure, when i remove admob plugin it works just fine, but when I add it to the project it crashes on Android 5.0 but works on every other android version, also I have sdk 21 and 22 installed

Answer (score 0):

Highly unlikely that is an Admob fault. All of the Admob code (AFAIK) is Java. That crash is a seg fault, ie below the Java framework.

Much more likely this is a problem with the Unity C code.
Or the particular ROM or drivers on the device being tested.

Comment: I don't know, other versions works fine, but in Android 5.0 it only plays for a few secs - 1 min at most and then it just crashes, I tested it in 3 devices with Android 5.0

Comment: Just saw an article talking about app crashes on Android 5.0, it appears to be a glitch of Lollipop, I've tried some alternatives to admob and none of them worked, always crash on Lollipop.

Comment: You should provide a reference for that, otherwise it's just rumour.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79729 I think that this memory leak is affecting my game when I add admob, leading it to close the app due the memory leak